# Unhandled exception logging for Windows Forms

Tags: .net, winforms, exception, logging

Is there anything like [ELMAH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELMAH) for Windows Forms?

I'm looking for a standard way to process unhandled exceptions and grab a screenshot and other environment information before packaging that up for support.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The very same Jeff Atwood coded a nice solution (albeit in VB.NET) which I had to modify and "fix" but that I am happily using since then.

You can view his solution [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/exception/ExceptionHandling.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

There is a nice [User Friendly Exception Handling](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/exception/ExceptionHandling.aspx) made by Jeff Atwood in 2004. I used it for several of our internal applications and it worked well.

Answer (score 1):

There is a commercial alternative called [{smartassembly}](http://www.smartassembly.com/product/index.aspx) that does error reporting.